# Load More Button Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ejs

I am trying to make a load more button on my website. When I click the load more button, the function starts, but the extra divs don't render.

Here is my backend code:

```js
app.get('/loadmore', async function(req, res) {
    console.log('Load More route accessed');
  
    const page = req.query.page || 1;
    const skip = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;
  
    const openProjects = await projectSchema
      .find({ Status: 'open', PaidFor: true })
      .sort({ ListedDate: -1 })
      .skip(skip);
  
    const otherProjects = await projectSchema
      .find({ Status: { $ne: 'open' }, PaidFor: true })
      .sort({ ListedDate: -1 })
      .skip(skip);
  
    const projects = openProjects.concat(otherProjects).slice(skip, skip + PAGE_SIZE);
  
    // Render project HTML code
    const projectHTML = projects
      .map(project => {
        return `
          <section class="box" style="margin: 1rem;">
            <a href="/project/${project.UniqueID}">
              <article class="media" style="background: white;">
                <div class="media-content">
                  <div class="content">
                    <p>
                      <span style="font-size: 2rem; color: #2d2d2d;margin-left: -2px;">Earn <strong style="color: #5cb85c">$${project.DollarAmount.toLocaleString()}!</strong></span>
                      <br>
                      <span><small><i class="fa-solid fa-clock" style="margin-right: 0.2rem;"></i> Listed ${getTimePassed(project.ListedDate)}</small></span>
                      ${
                        project.Status === 'open'
                          ? '<div class="status regular tag" style=""><p style="color:black">Open</p></div>'
                          : project.Status === 'claimed'
                          ? '<div class="status claimed tag">Claimed</div>'
                          : project.Status === 'closed'
                          ? '<div class="status closed tag">Closed</div>'
                          : project.Status === 'cancelled'
                          ? '<div class="status closed tag">Cancelled</div>'
                          : project.Status === 'completed'
                          ? '<div class="status claimed tag">Completed</div>'
                          : ''
                      }
                      <h3>${project.Title}</h3>
                    </p>
                    <a href="/project/${project.UniqueID}">
                      <p>${project.Description}</p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="tags">
                      ${project.Tags.map(tag => `<div class="tag">${tag}</div>`).join('')}
                    </div>
                    <nav class="level is-mobile">
                      <div class="level-left">
                        <small>
                          <button style="border-radius: 5px;" class="button bot_right is-small bountybutton has-text-black">View More</button>
                        </small>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </a>
          </section>
        `;
      })
      .join('');
  
    res.send(projectHTML); // Send the HTML response
  });
```

Frontend code

```html
  <div class="bounties">
    <% projects.forEach(function(project, index) { %>
  
    <section class="box" style="margin: 1rem;">
      <a href="/project/<%=project.UniqueID%>">
      <article class="media" style="background: white;">
        <div class="media-content">
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              <span style="font-size: 2rem; color: #2d2d2d;margin-left: -2px;">Earn <strong
                  style="color: #5cb85c">$<%=project.DollarAmount.toLocaleString()%>!</strong></span>
              <br>
              <span><small><i class="fa-solid fa-clock" style="margin-right: 0.2rem;"></i> Listed <%= getTimePassed(project.ListedDate) %> </small> </span>
                <% if(project.Status == 'open') { %>
                  <div class="status regular tag" style=""><p style="color:black">Open</p></div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'claimed') { %>  
                  <div class="status claimed tag">Claimed</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'closed') { %>  
                  <div class="status closed tag">Closed</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'cancelled') { %>  
                  <div class="status closed tag">Cancelled</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'completed') { %>  
                  <div class="status claimed tag">Completed</div> 
                <% } %>
  
<style>
                        .status.regular {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      font-weight: 400;
      opacity: 1;
      font-weight: 400;
      color:black

    }
    .tags {
      display: flex;
      gap: 8px;
    }

    .tag {
      
      border-radius: 16px;
      background-color: #ffc6c2;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #690D0D;
      background-color: #690D0D;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: .4s border-color;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tag:hover {
      border-color: #bb7676;
    }


    .tag,
    .status,
    .edit,
    .delete {
      padding: 8px 12px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .status.closed {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      background-color: #FFCCCB;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }
    .status.claimed {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }

                  </style>
               
              <h3>              <%=project.Title%>
              </h3>
            </a>
             <p> <%=project.Description%>            </p>

      <a href="/project/<%=project.UniqueID%>">

          </div>
          <% project.Tags.forEach(function(tag) { %>
            <div class="tag"><%= tag %></div>
          <% }); %>



          <nav class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left"><small>
               

                  
                  <button
                  style="border-radius: 5px;"
                  class="button bot_right is-small bountybutton has-text-black">View More</button>
              </small></div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </article>
    </a>
    </section>


    <% if (index === PAGE_SIZE - 1) { %>
          <button id="loadMoreButton" style="margin: 1rem; display: flex; justify-content: center;" class="button is-primary is-medium" onclick="loadMoreProjects()">Load More</button>
      <% } %>


    <% }); %> 

  </div>
</body>

  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Include jQuery library -->


<script>
    var PAGE_SIZE = 10;
    var page = 1;
  
    const loadMoreButton = document.getElementById('loadMoreButton');
    const projectContainer = document.querySelector('.bounties'); // Update the selector to match the container element
    console.log(projectContainer)
    // Event listener for the "Load More" button click
    loadMoreButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const page = getPageNumberFromURL(); // Implement the logic to get the current page number from the URL
      const nextPage = page + 1; // Calculate the next page number
  
      // Make an AJAX request to the "/loadmore" endpoint with the next page number
      $.ajax({
        url: '/loadmore',
        method: 'GET',
        data: { page: nextPage },
        success: function(response) {
          // Parse the response JSON
          const { projects } = JSON.parse(response);
  
          // Render project HTML code
          projectContainer.innerHTML += projects; // Use the projectContainer reference to append the projects
  
          // Update the page URL with the next page number
          updateURL(nextPage);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log('Error:', error);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          // Show a loading indicator or disable the button during the AJAX request
          loadMoreButton.disabled = true;
          loadMoreButton.innerText = 'Loading...';
        },
        complete: function() {
          // Hide the loading indicator or enable the button after the AJAX request completes
          loadMoreButton.disabled = false;
          loadMoreButton.innerText = 'Load More';
        }
      });
    });
  
    // Function to get the current page number from the URL
    function getPageNumberFromURL() {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      return parseInt(urlParams.get('page')) || 1;
    }
  
    // Function to update the page URL with the next page number
    function updateURL(page) {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      urlParams.set('page', page);
      const newURL = window.location.pathname + '?' + urlParams.toString();
      window.history.replaceState(null, '', newURL);
    }
  </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

When I click the load more button, it switches to disabled and "loading...", but the projects don't show.

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the frontend.

`res.send` sends text as a response, so `JSON.parse` fails.

Try removing `JSON.parse` in the `success` method:

```
const projects = response;
```

Also, there is no `loadMoreProjects()` function, so you need to remove `onclick="loadMoreProjects()` from the button, as you're adding click event listener.

That should work, but as the whole html container is being modified with new content, you'll probably need to get the button reference again from the `complete` method:

```
    complete: function() {

      // Hide the loading indicator or enable the button after the AJAX request completes
      document.getElementById('loadMoreButton').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('loadMoreButton').innerText = 'Load More';
    }
```

Also, the button event listener is lost, so you'll need to refactor the code to add the listener again, and move the ajax call to the function.

It might be done like this:

In your code, there is no `loadMoreProjects` function, you add click listener instead, which is lost when html gets updated.

So, you could simply turn that button click event listener into `loadMoreProjects` function, and leave `onclick="loadMoreProjects()`

So, try replacing button click listener with the missing `loadMoreProjects` function:

replace

```
loadMoreButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
//..
});
```

with

```
function loadMoreProjects() {
//...
}
```

and now after the html container is modified, the button will always call this function, while the click event listener would need to be assigned on every html update.